# PHP variables overwriting the whole session?

Tags: php, session

For some reason, if my $_SESSION looks something like this:
`Array (

[userid] => 123

[blah] => bleh

)`
When I do something like:
`$blah=array(1,2,3);`
It changes my whole $_SESSION. Is that normal, or is there something wrong that's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) enabled? Disable that.

Answer (score -2):

"Some types of data can not be serialized thus stored in sessions. It includes resource variables or objects with circular references (i.e. objects which passes a reference to itself to another object)."

[PHP session documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

I dont think you can store an array in a session like that

Comment: Yes, very wrong. Also the array he's written is the output of $_SESSION array itself, not a multi-dimensional array constructed from $_SESSION['...'].

Comment: Yup ur right, I am completely wrong, on both accounts. Time for bed me thinks